# Approval time for in app purchase product

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

For adding in app purchase products, how long does apple normally take to approve one of them? I have like hundreds of in app products and i wonder how long it will take for all to be approved.

Answer (score 2):

It usually takes anywhere from 1-2 weeks depending on how busy it is. If you have like hundreds it may take a few months to get them all approved but then again, apple doesn't check everything, just a lot of them so probably 1-3 months.